# Selecting next Span with className with Jquery selector

Tags: jquery

Struggling with Jquery selector to select

```
<span class='textContent'>
```

when *'edit_click'* class is clicked. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
<span>
    <i class='fa fa-pencil edit_click'></i>
</span>
<span class='textContent'>Hello</span>
```

Javascript event handler

```
$('.edit_click').click(function (e) {
    $(this).next('span.textContent').attr('contenteditable', 'true');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)  to get the reference of parent `span`, then `.next()` can be used on `span` to target immediately following sibling.

```
$(this).parent().next('span.textContent')
```

Comment: Sibling or parent? ;)

Comment: @GôTô, sibling of parent

Comment: you mean *uncle* then?

Answer (score 4):

Try to use the `closest()` function at this context to select the parent `span` element of `i`. After that use `.next()` since `span.textContent` is a sibling to the element which was previously selected with `closest`,

```
$('.edit_click').click(function (e) {
   $(this).closest('span').next(".textContent").attr('contenteditable', 'true');
});
```

And using `e.preventDefault` is pointless here as you bound event over an `i` tag, since it doesn't have any built in functionality with it.